# SQL Group by "Folder Name" by month and then total

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My new query is giving me few errors:

Error:  ORA-0093: SQL command not properly ended.

```
    select coalesce(a.group_name, 'Total') as group_name,
    sum(case when month (a.sent_date)=1 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as January,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=2 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as February,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=3 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as March,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=4 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as April,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=5 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as May,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=6 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as June,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=7 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as July,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=8 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as August,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=9 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as September,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=10 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as October,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=11 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as November,
    sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=12 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as December
    from c_group a
    where a.partner_id=123 AND
    a.sent_date >= '01-JAN-2012'
    and a.sent_date <= '31-DEC-2012'
    group by a.group_name with rollup;
```

=========

This is my first time posting here and also a beginner at queries.

I am running a query which returns various folder names for all days. I want to group by the folder name and do a sum of the totals for each folder name by months and then a total of each column at the bottom.  This is the query I am running:

```
select a.group_name, a.sent_date, a.total_sent
from 
c_group a
where
a.partner_id=123
and a.sent_date >= '01-JAN-2012'
and a.sent_date <= '31-DEC-2012'
```

Displays as follows:

```
GROUP_NAME  SENT_DATE   TOTAL_SENT
Group A     1-Jan-12    37
Group B     3-Jan-12    25
Group C     1-May-12    10
Group D     1-May-12    8
Group D     1-Jan-12    11
Group A     1-Dec-12    9
```

I need the results to display as:

```
           January  February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December
Group A                                             
Group B                                             
Group C                                             
Group D                                             
...                                             
....                                                
...                                             
....                                                
Total       Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above    Sum of above
```

Comment: You are looking for `pivot` probably.

Comment: What would the query look like using pivot?

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine conditional aggregation with `rollup`:

```
select coalesce(a.group_name, 'Total') as group_name,
       sum(case when month(a.sent_date) = 1 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as January,
       sum(case when month(a.sent_date) = 2 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as February,
       . . .
       sum(case when month(a.sent_date) = 12 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as December
from c_group a
where a.partner_id = 123 AND
      a.sent_date >= '01-JAN-2012' AND
      a.sent_date <= '31-DEC-2012'
group by a.group_name with rollup;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Trying this now.  Will keep you posted.

Comment: Gives an error saying: Missing right parenthesis. Error at line 14 column: 39

Comment: Just need to close the SUM functions: sum(case when month(a.sent_date = 1 then a.total_sent else 0 end)) as January

Comment: Tried that. Same error.sum(case when month(a.sent_date = 10 then a.total_sent else 0 end)) as October,
       sum(case when month(a.sent_date = 11 then a.total_sent else 0 end)) as November,
       sum(case when month(a.sent_date = 12 then a.total_sent else 0 end)) as December

Comment: Using oracle SQL developer. I resolved that error by using the following format:     sum(case when month(a.sent_date)=1 then a.total_sent else 0 end) as January,  -- But new error on line 30, column 22: command not properly ended for:   group by a.group_name with rollup;

Comment: @Gordon Any advice?  2 errors.  If I do group by -- then SQL command ended improperly.  If I don't use, group by then says "Month" is an invalid identifier.

Comment: @Yas . . . Missing the closing parens around `month()`.

Comment: Updated the SQL. New error on the last line that SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you have any other advice to correct the issue?  I have updated the query according to your recommendation on the initial question.